# Azure Virtual Machine and Azure SQL Database: optimal deployment for performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

The solution consists of an SQL Database and desktop application working hard with that DB. DB Deployed as Azure SQL Database, application running on Azure Virtual Machine with Windows Server onboard. What is the deployment guidelines for this two services in Azure? I want to achieve max performance. Should they both be located in same resource group?

Comment: There's no right answer to this - lots of deployment options, scaling options, networking options, etc.  Max performance could mean any number of things (networking, number of connections, query processing time, etc). Aside from colocating your services within the same region, this doesn't have an exact answer. Plus it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get your app and the database located as close as possible so yes the same resource group.

Make sure you do not have Mars enabled (MultipleActiveResultSets in connection string).

Make sure you do use connection pooling.

Read this to understand what you are dealing with:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/improving-the-quality-of-sql-server-database-connections-in-the-cloud/

Ed